# php Image returning blank

Tags: php

I am able to upload an image file path to the database, although when trying to update it, the file name show as blank on the db.

```
<input type='file' id='image' name='image'>

$target_dir = "assets/img/products/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

$img = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $target_file)


$sql = "UPDATE products SET image = '$img' WHERE product_ID='$index'";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: what is the result, when you output $target_file?

Comment: Your update query has some errors like the opening quote is not closed plus you are also missing a WHERE clause right?

Comment: ah sorry yeah forgot to include the where, and the target file just returns "assets/img/products/"

Comment: use enctype in "form" tag:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably reposting the same form, and the input [name="image"] is empty, so you update the field with an empty value

You should check if you have any file posted before performing the update on the image field:

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['iamge']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {  
 // perform update
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use enctype in form tag

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Comment: This should have been a comment.